# Parsing in pyspark, json stored as string. Need to store as json only

Tags: python, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data stored as array of string. Internally this string is json/tuple.

I need to get EID, and reason from it
Input:
['{"Eid":'1',"reason":"null","deptID":{1,2,3}}','{"Eid":'2',"reason":"happy","deptID":{2,3}}']

I need to parse this to get eid and reason only. I want each json stored as string to be in json format. Like below.
[{"Eid":'1',"reason":"null"},
{"Eid":'2',"reason":"happy"}]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is parsing JSON string using `from_json` and schema, then extracting the fields you want and converting it back to JSON using `to_json`.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [
    '{"Eid":"1","reason":"null","deptID":"{1,2,3}"}',
    '{"Eid":"2","reason":"happy","deptID":"{2,3}"}',
]

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("Eid", StringType(), True),
        StructField("reason", StringType(), True),
        StructField("deptID", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([[x] for x in data], ["value"])
df = (
    df.withColumn("data", F.from_json(F.col("value"), schema))
    .withColumn("Eid", F.col("data")["Eid"])
    .withColumn("reason", F.col("data")["reason"])
    .withColumn("json", F.to_json(F.struct([F.col("Eid"), F.col("reason")])))
    .select(["value", "json"])
)

df.show(20, False)
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+   
|value                                         |json                        |
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|{"Eid":"1","reason":"null","deptID":"{1,2,3}"}|{"Eid":"1","reason":"null"} |
|{"Eid":"2","reason":"happy","deptID":"{2,3}"} |{"Eid":"2","reason":"happy"}|
+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```